# Ordenar campos por contenido en sql server

Tags: sql, server, orderby

Tengo una tabla de base de datos que debe ordenase de acuerdo al valor de un campo en forma ascendente. Los valores posibles son: 001, 003, 005,011, 014, 020,021, 022.... . El tema es que el registro con el valor 011 debe ser igual el último de todos. Debe quedar 001,003,005,014,020,021,..., 011

Si pueden ayudarme a como crear este sentencia con order by.

Es una tabla con comprobante de compras. Cada comprobantes contiene un campo llamado tipo de comprobante. Puede hacer mas de un comprobante con un mismo tipo.
Los comprantes de compras deben ser ordenado segun este orden:

1° Tipo de Comprobante: 001, 002, 003, 019, 020, 021, 011 Monotributista.

2° Fecha del Comprobante: Ascendente

3° Numero de Documento Comprobante del Proveedor: Ascendente

Aclaración:Como los comprobantes 011 – Comprobante C no tienen alícuota quedan de últimos .

Lo dificil esta en la aclaración como  llevar los comrprobantes de tipo 011 en las ultimas posiciones de la tabla.

Gracias.

Comment: Vos queres ordenar una tabla... de forma desordenada? mostra los datos, mostra tu tabla, mostra lo que intentaste y mostra como quiere quedar...

Comment: con solo order by no vas a poder.. la base de datos no hace magia y no sabe de reglas de negocios.. solo sabe ordenar numeros y letras.. no reglas de negocios.... asi que, que fue lo que intentaste?

Comment: Es sencillo debo ordenarle en forma ascendenete por tipo de comporbante, luego por  fecha de comprobante y al final por número de comprobante.  Pero hay una  execepcion los comprobantes con el tipo de comprobane = 011  no estaran colocados ordenadamente segun los criterios.  Siempre van a quedar como ultimos en la tabla.

Comment: genial.. si es sencillo, que fue lo que intentaste?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ordenar usando expresiones como un `CASE`.

```
SELECT *
FROM TablaOConsulta
ORDER BY CASE WHEN TipoComprobante = '011' THEN 'ZZZ' ELSE TipoComprobante END;
```

Sin embargo, esto puede volverse complicado si se agregan excepciones. Lo ideal, sería crear una nueva tabla en la que tengas asignado el orden.

```
CREATE TABLE TiposComprobante(
    TipoComprobante char(3),
    Descripción     varchar(100),
    Orden           int
);
```

De esa forma, solo tienes que agregar la tabla con un JOIN para poder obtener el orden en el que deben de aparecer.

```
SELECT toc.*
FROM TablaOConsulta   AS toc
JOIN TiposComprobante AS tc ON toc.TipoComprobante = tc.TipoComprobante
ORDER BY tc.orden;
```

Comment: Tengo dos preguntas Luis Cazares respecto a la primera solución:

Comment: Luis Cazares. Te agregue dos preguntas más debajo de tu respuesta. Me pueden ayudar mucho si podes responderme.  Desde ya gracias.

Comment: No deberías editar la respuesta para agregar preguntas. La expresión CASE sustituye únicamente a una columna, por lo que el resto de las columnas que definen el orden deben quedar fuera. La expresión CASE está sustituyendo '011' por 'ZZZ' para que lo ordene al final.

Comment: Diculpe por la edicón de la respuesta. Soy nuevo en el foro y me falta mas ejercitación en los formatos
En cuanto a la respuesta de la primer pregunta que habia hecho.  Si dice que sustituye el 011 por el ZZZ, entonces yo perderia el valor 011? y no tengo que perderlos, se tiene que mantener 011 en los registros. Como hago para matenerlos. Debo hacer un select o un update a continuación para recuperar el 011 en los registros?.  Gracias.

Comment: No se pierde nada, solo cambia el valor para ordenar, pero no cambia el valor que se refleja en la consulta.

Comment: Gracias por todo Luis Cazares me ha servido mucho tu ayuda.